# Explode sql result and use in n different select tags

Tags: php, html, mysql

So as the Title says,my problem is :

I have column in SQL table like this:

### Something

### 30,20,10,11,22

I know  how to select the value of column and explode it :

```
$Var = $Mysql->query("SELECT Something FROM Something ");
explode ($Var);
```

When i explode the result  i need to make,in this case 5 option tags selected in 5 different select tags depending on the number that i get(numbers from SQL = value of option tag),and i need to make in this case 5 different select tags
So everything needs to by dynamically made,depending of the SQL column.

Please help,
Sorry if this a stupid question,I'm new to PHP,SQL.
I hope you all understand what i want and i hope you can help me . :)

Comment: It's not good practice to explode a SQL result to get more values. You should remodel your database.

Comment: I know,but this is how i need to do it,i can't change database. :( Can it be done?

Comment: **Nice specification** But we dont code to specs. **If all else fails**....Try looking at the manual [Foreach verb](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Well I'm not really sure what you mean by your "option tags" and all that, but I do know that if you `$tags = explode( ",", $Var ); ` you will get an array with 5 different, separate values in it. You can then print_r the array to see what it looks like, use a `foreach` loop to iterate through it, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit confuesd by you question but could it be something like this?

```
$result = explode(',', $var);
for ($i = 1;$i <= count($result); $i++)
    echo "<select name='select".$i."'>";
    foreach ($result as $option) {
        echo "<option value='".$option."'>".$option."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

If you just want one select with all options though use this:

```
$result = explode(',', $var);
echo "<select name='select'>";
foreach ($result as $option) {
    echo "<option value='".$option."'>".$option."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Ty mate, i think this will help me .